# Where do inserted documents go in a benchrun?

Tags: mongodb

I made the following attempt to use `benchrun` to insert documents:

```
> use benchmark
switched to db benchmark
> db.createCollection("bench")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> ops = [{op: "insert", ns: "db.bench", safe: false, doc: {"a": 1}}]
.....
> benchRun({parallel: 8, seconds: 10, ops: ops})
{
    "note" : "values per second",
    "errCount" : NumberLong(0),
    "trapped" : "error: not implemented",
    "insertLatencyAverageMicros" : 4.349606891531182,
    "insert" : 41210,
    "query" : 0,
    "update" : 0,
    "delete" : 0,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 413
}
> db.bench.find()
>
```

Benchrun did not report any error, but by the end of it, no document is found in the collection.

Where have they gone?

Comment: Why should `benchrun` put documents into your collection? Where is it said? AFAIK `benchrun` is just a testing tool.

Comment: @u_mulder All right, then what has been done instead of putting documents into the collection?

Comment: Maybe some inserts of documents have beeen done and some statistics counted, and after that all docs has been removed so your collection remains as it was before tests, I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ops` variable you specified the namespace as `ns: "db.bench"`.  This will insert into the database called `db` and the collection called `bench`.

You should be able to find the records inserted with:

```
db.getSiblingDB('db').bench.find()
```

To output to the collection you expected, your namespace should be "benchmark.bench":

```
ops = [{op: "insert", ns: "benchmark.bench", safe: false, doc: {"a": 1}}]
```

Also, it is not necessary to run `createCollection()` before `benchRun()`. If the collection does not exist it will be created. Depending on what you are trying to observe, you may instead wish to drop your `benchmark` database or `bench` collection prior to invoking `benchRun()`.